# Why dimension of invariant subspace of inertia group is nonzero?

Tags: number-theory, representation-theory

Let $L/K$ be a finite Galois extension of number fields. Suppose $\rho \colon \mathrm{Gal}(L/K) \to \mathrm{GL}_d(\mathbb{C})=\mathrm{Aut}(V)$ is a finite Galois representation. Then Artin $L$-function is defined as
$$L(\rho, s) = \prod_{\mathfrak{p} \in \operatorname{Spec}\mathcal{O}_L} \frac{1}{\det(1-Nm(\mathfrak{p})^{-s}\rho|_{G_{\mathfrak{p}}}(\mathrm{Frob}_{\mathfrak{p}}),V^{I_{\mathfrak{p}}})}$$
where $G_{\mathfrak{p}}, I_{\mathfrak{p}}$ are corresponding decomposition and inertia subgroup. My question is why $\dim V^{I_{\mathfrak{p}}} \neq 0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it? It's pretty easy to construct one-dimensional Artin representations such that $V^{I_{\mathfrak{p}}}=0$ for some prime, consider a quadratic extension $K/\Bbb Q$ and the unique nontrivial irreducible representation of the Galois group.

Comment: If $dimV^{I_\mathfrak{p}}=0$, then should we take $det$ of a $0 \times 0$ matix is $1$?

Comment: @bd1234 yes, the $0 \times 0$-matrix is the identity matrix, after all